# How to get comments of Facebook link

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some trouble with de Facebook API (PHP SDK). I'm working in a CMS, and when a new post/page is created, this can be shared to Facebook. Like this:

```
$response = ( new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
        'link'    => $url,
        'message' => $message
    )
) )->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

After I posted the link, I'll get the ID and save it to the database:

```
$response->getProperty( 'id' );
```

The ID is something like this: 1387893784860228_1395000904149516

Now I want to pull the comments, so I try this:

```
$response = ( new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'GET', '/1387893784860228_1395000904149516/comments'
) )->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

The result is empty, but I posted multiple comments, does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Do you have permission to read that user’s wall posts?

Comment: I'm using the Open Graph Test User, so I full rights I think. I can post to his wall, so why should I not have rights to read it?